# Do I need to sign my .jar application files to get them to run in OS X or Windows?

Tags: java, macos, sign

I have almost completed my first Java application and have compiled it as a .jar (with a second .jar in the accompanying 'lib' file).  To my surprise this totally unsigned application runs on my Mac (OS X 10.11 El Capitan) without even requesting an administrator password.  This surprises me as

1. I've always had to type an administrator password when installing apps on a Mac before, and
2. I thought SIP was supposed to stop unsigned applications running.  This is the same machine I used for most of the programming and for the compilation.

So my question(s):

- Will my unsigned Java application run on any Mac with a compatible JRE installed?
- If not, do I need signing keys and certificates from Apple or will any do? What about Windows (and indeed Linux) (it seems lots of people have been having difficulty getting .jars to run in Windows 10)?

I should mention that I am going to try to sign the application anyway, to reassure users and avoid the danger of people passing off malware as my program.  I'm a total novice when it comes to all this!

Answer (score 4):

The reason you don't need superuser privileges is that you're not actually running a *new* application, merely invoking an existing one (java) with different arguments.

java is the application that is installed on your machine and *has* been signed.  Your jar file is, as far as the OS is concerned, just a data file you give to java.

Think of it like unzipped a file or viewing a text file - the application used is different from the file it operates on

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks.  It's a little scary as my application is capable of deleting files and folders (albeit duplicates that it has created).  I did have to put in my administrator password to move it into the applications folder - so without this it is only a single-user installation, not system-wide.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to, but to have the Jar run without having to change the security details on the computer, you should do this just to tell the user, *"I made this, and nothing will happen when to your computer when you run my application"*.

"An application without a certificate (i.e. unsigned apps), or missing application Name and Publisher information are blocked by default. Running this kind of application is potentially unsafe and present higher level of risk." - [Java Applications Blocked](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml)

Comment: Very interesting thanks.  In the light of what MrWiggles said above, do I take it the passage you quote means that _the JRE_, rather than the OS, might block an unsigned .jar application?  If so I wonder why it didn't for me?  Might it be because it was written/compiled on the same machine?  If so I wonder if there is a way of tricking the JRE into thinking it was not so I can see exactly how it would behave on a user's machine?  So many questions!